# Check for last row

Tags: views, 8

Is there any way to find the last row from view itself.I have to add some extra html for the last item. I know we can do this using view's twig template, but I want to know is there any option in the view itself to check the last item.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use hook to achieve this. You can use [template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted/8.2.x) hook function and implement code as below *(it already does what you need it to do)*. Add this hook to your **themename.theme** file and don't forget to clear cache.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted($variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  // Select view by machine name `blog` and display machine name `block_2`
  if ($view->id() === 'blog' && $view->current_display === 'block_2') {
   $rows = $variables['rows'];

   // Get number of rows
   $rows_size = count($rows) - 1;

   // Add custom CSS class ONLY to last row
   // This is what you want to achieve
   $variables['rows'][$rows_size]['attributes']->addClass('my-super-class');

   // OR Iterate over each row and do something
   // This is in case you want to alter each view's row result
   foreach($rows as $id => $row) {
     $variables['rows'][$id]['content']['my_custom_field'] = 'my custom value';
   }
  }
}
```